# Modification done to list.copy() apply to the list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to model a chess game in python 3 with object-oriented programming.
One of the class i am using is Board which contain a matrix (8x8 list of list) with the other object.
I also created a simple `__str__` method to visualize the chess board.

Here is some part of the Board class definition :

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, pieces: list):
        self.container = [[pieces[i] for i in range(8)],  # Whites
                          [pieces[i] for i in range(8, 16)],  # White pawns
                          [None] * 8,
                          [None] * 8,
                          [None] * 8,
                          [None] * 8,
                          [pieces[i] for i in range(16, 24)],  # Black pawns
                          [pieces[i] for i in range(24, 32)]]  # Blacks


    def __str__(self):
        str_copy = self.container.copy()

        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                if isinstance(str_copy[i][j], King):
                    str_copy[i][j] = 'K'
                elif isinstance(str_copy[i][j], Queen):
                    str_copy[i][j] = 'Q'
                elif isinstance(str_copy[i][j], Rook):
                    str_copy[i][j] = 'R'
                elif isinstance(str_copy[i][j], Knight):
                    str_copy[i][j] = 'N'
                elif isinstance(str_copy[i][j], Bishop):
                    str_copy[i][j] = 'B'
                elif isinstance(str_copy[i][j], Pawn):
                    str_copy[i][j] = 'P'
                elif str_copy[i][j] is None:
                    str_copy[i][j] = '_'

        return ''.join([str(line) + '\n' for line in str_copy])
```

My problem is that at some point in my code `Board.container` seems to be overwritten by the `str_copy`.
I really can't figure out why. 
Here is the full code if you want to have a look at it: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/VwTJ3XjY)

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: You're only copying the outer container (list), which still holds references to the same inner ones. Use `str_copy = copy.deepcopy(self.container)`.

Comment: [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) can copy class instances
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612990/2630643

Comment: `__str__` looks overly complicated. `str` values are immutable, so there's no reason to create copies of anything.

Comment: I rushed a bit in closing the question. Considering the current error it is indeed a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list, but it's also an *XY Problem*.  I was preparing an answer, but @chepner beat me to it :) .

Answer (score 0):

This is overly complicated. First, each piece should have its own `__str__` method, for instance,

```
class Bishop:
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'B'
```

Then

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, pieces: list):
        self.container = [pieces[:8],  # white back row
                          pieces[8:16],  # white pawns
                          [None] * 8,
                          [None] * 8,
                          [None] * 8,
                          [None] * 8,
                          pieces[16:24],  # black pawns
                          pieces[24:32]   # black back row
                         ]

    @staticmethod
    def _square_to_str(x):
        return '_' if x is None else str(x)

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(''.join(map(Board._square_to_str, row))
                          for row in self.container)
```

Answer (score 0):

I rushed a bit in closing the question. Considering the current error, it is indeed a *dupe* of [[SO]: How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list). 
But on a closer look, it's acutally an *XY Problem*. Simply duplicating that object for display purposes only, is not just ugly, but it's also unnecessary. Here's a more elegant alternative:

Add a new (class) method to *Piece* (to avoid altering *__str__* or *__repr__* behavior, I named it *letter*):

```py
@classmethod
def letter(cls):
    raise NotImplementedError
```

and override it in all its children (*King*, *Queen*, *Rook*, *Knight*, *Bishop*, *Pawn*). For example, in *King*'s case it should be:

```py
@classmethod
def letter(cls):
    return "K"
```

I guess it's pretty obvious how it would look like for the others.

Then, *Board.__str__* could be something like:

```py
def __str__(self):
    return "\n".join("".join(getattr(piece, "letter", lambda: "_")() for piece in line) for line in self.container)
```

Comment: Thank you CristiFati and @chepner.
Its true that `copy.hardcopy() did solve my problem but your solutions is much more elegant.
This issue helped me to have a better understanding of the "everything is an object" paradigm in Python.
Again, thanks a lot for your help !